# Load div with content on button click

Tags: jquery, html

i want to load some divs with jquery according to buttons.
For example we have

```
<div class="content">
    <button type="button" name="addteam">Add New Team</button>
    <button type="button" name="addplayer">Add New Player</button>
    <button type="button" name="addgame">Add New Game</button> 
    <button type="button" name="deleteteam">Delete Team</button>
    <button type="button" name="deleteplayer">Delete Player</button>
    <button type="button" name="deletegame">Delete Game</button>
    <button type="button" name="addplayermatch">Add Player To Match</button>
    <button type="button" name="deleteplayermatch">Remove Player From Match</button>
</div>
```

Now if the user clicks on say `Add New Player` i want it to show the

```
<div class="addnewplayer">
    <h2>Add New Player</h2>
    <form action="addplayer.php" method="POST"/>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
        <p>Sex: <input type="text" name="sex" /></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
        <p>Birth: <input type="text" name="birth" /></p>
        <p>League: <input type="text" name="league" /></p>
        <p>Team: <select name="teamName" class="addPTeam"><script>fillTeams();</script></select></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I just picked up jquery this week. I understand i can make a function onClick for each button but is that wise enough? And then use `$(".addnewplayer").html(....` and put the whole div info in there?

If you could point out the best way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Have each div hidden and just show or hide on click

Comment: Do you have different forms for each(like.. Add New Team, Add New Player etc.) ?

Comment: Yes, different one for each of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vjJ7W/)

```
<head>
<style>
.content { display:none }
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".but").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#"+this.id+"div").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navigation">
    <button class="but" type="button" id="addteam">Add New Team</button>
    <button class="but" type="button" id="addplayer">Add New Player</button>
    <button class="but" type="button" id="addgame">Add New Game</button> 
    <button class="but" type="button" id="deleteteam">Delete Team</button>
    <button class="but" type="button" id="deleteplayer">Delete Player</button>
    <button class="but" type="button" id="deletegame">Delete Game</button>
    <button class="but" type="button" id="addplayermatch">Add Player To Match</button>
    <button class="but" type="button" id="deleteplayermatch">Remove Player From Match</button>
</div>

<div id="addplayerdiv" class="content">
    <h2>Add New Player</h2>
    <form ...>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="addteamdiv" class="content">
    <h2>Add New Team</h2>
    <form ...>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

If the HTML is extensive, you can load the content from an html file:

```
$(function() {
  $(".but").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load(this.id+".html");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template html to specify the contents for each of the buttons content, then do something like

You can do soemthing like

```
<div class="content">
    <button type="button" name="addteam" data-href="addteam.html">Add New Team</button>
    <button type="button" name="addplayer" data-href="addplayer.html">Add New Player</button>
    <button type="button" name="addgame" data-href="addgame.html">Add New Game</button>
    ....
</div>
```

then

```
//target all buttons elements with data-href property
$('button[data-href]').click(function () {
    //load the contents of the url specified by the href into addnewplayer
    $(".addnewplayer").load($(this).data('href'));
})
```

then in `addteam.html`

```
<div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider hiding the div's instead of loading them:

```
<div class="content">
<button type="button" name="addteam">Add New Team</button>
<button type="button" name="addplayer">Add New Player</button>
<button type="button" name="addgame">Add New Game</button> 
<button type="button" name="deleteteam">Delete Team</button>
<button type="button" name="deleteplayer">Delete Player</button>
<button type="button" name="deletegame">Delete Game</button>
<button type="button" name="addplayermatch">Add Player To Match</button>
<button type="button" name="deleteplayermatch">Remove Player From Match</button>
</div>
...
<div id="addplayer" class="panel">
<h2>Add New Player</h2>
<form action="addplayer.php" method="POST"/>
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p>Sex: <input type="text" name="sex" /></p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p>Birth: <input type="text" name="birth" /></p>
<p>League: <input type="text" name="league" /></p>
<p>Team: <select name="teamName" class="addPTeam"><script>fillTeams();</script></select></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

css:

```
.panel {
    display: none;
}

.panel.current {
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".content").on("click", "button", function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $(".panel").removeClass("current");
    $("div#" + name).addClass("current");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend show/hide option **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/kBcvS/2)**

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(event){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#" + name + "div").slideToggle("slow");
    })
});
```

In this example you create a form inside a div and place it after the button. The div id needs to be the button name + "div". Then the function knows which div to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax so that the div will dynamically loaded each time when you click on the buttons

```
   <div class="content">
    <button type="button" name="addteam" onclick="onshow()>Add New Team</button>
    <button type="button" name="addplayer">Add New Player</button>
    <button type="button" name="addgame">Add New Game</button> 
    <button type="button" name="deleteteam">Delete Team</button>
    <button type="button" name="deleteplayer">Delete Player</button>
    <button type="button" name="deletegame">Delete Game</button>
    <button type="button" name="addplayermatch">Add Player To Match</button>
    <button type="button" name="deleteplayermatch">Remove Player From Match</button>
</div>
   <div class="addnewplayer">

</div>
    <script language="javascript">

        function onshow()
        {

         $.ajax({
            type:'POST'
            url:context+'/newteam',
           success:function(data) { 
              $( "div.addnewplayer" ).html( data );


            }

          });

        }



     then in newteam.html

<div class="addnewplayer">
    <h2>Add New Player</h2>
    <form action="addplayer.php" method="POST"/>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
        <p>Sex: <input type="text" name="sex" /></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
        <p>Birth: <input type="text" name="birth" /></p>
        <p>League: <input type="text" name="league" /></p>
        <p>Team: <select name="teamName" class="addPTeam"><script>fillTeams();</script></select></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why post? why not just $("#content").load(...) ?